# Why getting a 500 at my new .NET Core 2.0 WebApi endpoint when using DI?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I set up a **new Controller** and when I call the endpoint (with swagger), I get always a **500** returned. To check that is not about incorrect code I set only the line return Ok("received");
When I take out the **dependency injection** (DI)  from the controller constructor, than I get a 200.
May does some body has a idea what could cause the problem and what could be a solution?

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v1/dataPicker/startProcess")]
public class StartProcessController : Controller
{
    private IStartProcessBusinessComponent BusinessComponent { get; }

    public StartProcessController(IStartProcessBusinessComponent startProcessBusinessComponent)
    {
        BusinessComponent = startProcessBusinessComponent;
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetProcessStart([FromBody]StartProcessWrapper startProcessWrapper)
    {
        return Ok("received");
    }
}



public interface IStartProcessBusinessComponent
{
    Task SetProcessStartAsync(StartProcessWrapper startProcessWrapper);
}


class StartProcessBusinessComponent : IStartProcessBusinessComponent
{
    public StartProcessBusinessComponent( ) {}

    public async Task SetProcessStartAsync(StartProcessWrapper startProcessWrapper) { }
}
```

When I take the DI off, than I get a 200 returned.
But I need the DI.

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v1/dataPicker/startProcess")]
public class StartProcessController : Controller
{
    private IStartProcessBusinessComponent BusinessComponent { get; }

    public StartProcessController( ) { }

    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetProcessStart([FromBody]StartProcessWrapper startProcessWrapper)
    {
        return Ok("received");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to fix

1. Instead `[FromBody]` use `[FromServices]` to get component from DI
2. Declare in DI `StartProcessBusinessComponent` as `IStartProcessBusinessComponent` using for example `services.AddTransient<IStartProcessBusinessComponent, StartProcessBusinessComponent>();`

And that should work

Comment: Thanks Piotr.
I got it working.
I did change:
1) set public for the class StartProcessBusinessComponent
2) kept FromBody, that works
3) add the line you suggested to Startup